# Display an images using data-bind knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am working on a table for a web application using MVC and knockout.js. I have experience doing web development but this is my first time using knockout. I currently have a table with 3 columns. The 2nd and 3rd are populated using a knockout function that displays the data. I tried to set up the first column the same way except using an image instead of text. I keep getting a broken image icon and an error in the brower's console.

The error the browser is giving me: 
GET http://**hostinfo**/Sponsor/~PracticeAppImagesGWC.png 404 (Not Found)

This is my table:

```
<table id="sponsorTable">
    <thead><tr>
        <th></th><th id="sponsor">Sponsor</th><th id="description">Description</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Sponsors">
        <tr>
            <td><img data-bind="attr: {src: Image}" /></td>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td class="sTableInfo" data-bind="text: Description"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my function for filling the table. (columns 2 and 3 fill properly)

```
function pageModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Sponsors = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function Sponsor( _image, _name, _descrip)
{
    var self = this;

    self.Image = ko.observable(_image);
    self.Name = ko.observable(_name);
    self.Description = ko.observable(_descrip);
}

var viewModel = new pageModel();
viewModel.Sponsors().push(new Sponsor("~/Images/GWC.png", "name1", "info1"));
viewModel.Sponsors().push(new Sponsor("second image would go here", "name2", "info2"));

$(function () {

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
})
```

I think something is escaping the slashes in the img source link, but I'm not sure and I can't figure out why.

UPDATE: my compiler is telling me this for the image tag: "Validation (HTML5): Element 'img' is missing required attribute 'src'."

Comment: The tilda ~ is not available in this context, it's only server side

Comment: `<img src="~/Images/TrueBlood.png" height="175" width="175" alt="Hammer True Blood" />` i use the tilda on another page (example here) and it works just fine.

Comment: I think your server interprets this. Try to do a "view source" on your page, I think you will have the full path

Comment: I updated the question.. added some new info I discovered at the bottom. Hope it helps with figuring this out. I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `push`must be on the [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) itself, you need to remove the parenthesis:

```
var viewModel = new pageModel();
viewModel.Sponsors.push(new Sponsor("~/Images/GWC.png", "name1", "info1"));
viewModel.Sponsors.push(new Sponsor("second image would go here", "name2", "info2"));
```

Comment: Everything worked before I tried to add the image. the image is the only thing not working. Trying this didn't work either. The console error did change though. 
GET http://**host info**:54137/Sponsor/~/Images/GWC.png 404 (Not Found)
It looks like its just trying to go to the wrong folder now. Idk why its looking inside the /Sponsor/ folder.

Comment: @Jason9024 Yes, because of the ~, I must say I told you :)

Comment: so i just need to give it the full file location? I've tried giving it more path info but nothing seems to work. :( Im so frustrated right now. I hate not being able to figure things out.

Comment: @Jason9024 You can use relative path with `../` syntax if you prefer. Oh wait, I think you can simply do `/Images/GWC.png`

Comment: the combination of his edit to the push and your relative path suggestion fixed the problem! thanks guys.

Comment: Both were mine though :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass just image name from viewmodel, and static folder path can be append like this.

```
// in viewmodel
viewModel.Sponsors().push(new Sponsor("GWC.png", "name1", "info1"));
// inside table
<td><img data-bind="attr: {src:'/Image/'+ Image}" /></td>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: still getting the broken image icon.

Comment: Either image is not available or path is wrong. you can try changing  or adding ~ the path. need to know directory arrangement of your project..

Comment: I've got the project folder. Then inside there I have 9 folders. One of those 9 is the Images folder where the image is located.